# Output one field, Output the next based on true or false

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm stuck outputting data from a table like this. This is a table for profiles.

```
CREATE TABLE `prod_profiles` (
 `p_add` VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `p_add_s` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `p_phone` VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `p_phone_s` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 //and many more
  )
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Over here, p_add is the address, p_add_s (anything with the _s) is the part which decides if a user would like to display this data or not (0 is display, 1 is hide).

I need to display data like: (this is the admin section)

```
Address data goes here if (p_add_s = 0) {echo 'Hide';} else {echo 'Unhide';}
Phone data goes here if (p_phone_s = 0) {echo 'Hide';} else {echo 'Unhide';}
```

My problem is how do i tell php to print the first column and then check the _s columns value without using all the columns names in php like below. I'm lost here.

The way I'm doing it now is:

```
    while($form_data = mysql_fetch_array($exe_prof_form))
    {
    echo $form_data['sc_p_add']; if ($form_data['sc_p_add_s'] ==0){echo "Hide";}else{echo "Show";
    //Remaining fields go here
    // Any way I can get rid of these fields and do what I'm trying?
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is.  I just don't want to use all the field names like $form_data['sc_p_add']; if ($form_data['sc_p_add_s'] ==0){echo "Hide";}else{echo "Show";} There are 9 fields now and more may be added. Any way to avoid this part making it just a few lines of code.

Comment: So the question is not really about SQL, is it? You seem to want to do all the processing in PHP. I mean, if that is so, please consider removing the `sql` tag.

Comment: Anything would do. If its achievable in php, that's fine, if its achievable in sql that's ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I came up with this: (Warning: Ugly Code ahead)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exe_prof_form)) {   
for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($exe_prof_form);$i+=2) 
{
echo $i." ".$row[$i];
$r=$i+1;
echo ($row[$r] == 0) ? " Hide <br />" : " Show <br />";
}
}
```

Does the job... Tell me what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
$fields = array('sc_p_add', 'sc_p_phone');

while($form_data = mysql_fetch_array($exe_prof_form))
{
    foreach($fields as $field){
        echo $field; 
        echo ($form_data[$field.'_s'] == 0) ? "Hide" : "Show";
    }
    //Remaining fields go here
    // Any way I can get rid of these fields and do what I'm trying?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it directly in sql statement? It will make your job easier.

```
SELECT p_add as `Address`,
       IF(p_add_s = 0, 'Show', 'Hide') as `AddressStatus`,
       p_phone as `PhoneNumber`,
       IF(p_phone_s = 0, 'Show', 'Hide') as `PhoneStatus`,
FROM prod_profiles
```

Comment: in principal a good idea, but i must say it don't like the idea to have my "modal", or query in this case, have presentation logic in them. besides if, as he stated in the comment, wants to add more fields, he have to modify the query each time. (in my answer its only extending the array)

Comment: so what's the matter if the OP wants to add more fields later? i just suggested the easiest wayto the OP. I think its better than to add condition for each record in the loop :D

Comment: Outputting this will require me to do the same thing as I originally did right?